# How to get multiple predictions rather than a focal prediction from multinomial regression model (i.e., split by factor variable)

Tags: r, data-visualization, prediction, multinomial

I want to run a multinomial regression to get the average frequency of each choice of a close question, split by a factor (gender: male/female).

### Background

I want to compare 4 types of cheeses to measure each one's popularity, out of 4 possibilities: cheddar, mozzarella, gouda, and brie. I go out and ask 200 people for their preferred cheese. Each person selects only one choice out of the 4 types. I end up collecting some demographics information as well, including gender, age, and weight.

Upon finishing data collection, I want to see the proportion of popularity of each cheese type (together they sum to 100%). Since I want to control for `gender`, `age`, and `weight`, I think that a multinomial regression is suitable here.

But I'm also very interested in seeing how results differ between males and females, and I want to include `gender` in my model as a factor. How can I generate a twofold prediction based on my (multinomial) model, that would get predicted values for females and males separately so I could compare between the two gender levels?

### Data

```r
library(truncnorm)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(999)

cheese_df <-
  tibble(
    age = round(rtruncnorm(
      n = 200,
      a = 20,
      b = 80,
      mean = 25,
      sd = 25.09
    )),
    cheese_response = as_factor(sample(
      c("cheddar", "mozzarella", "gouda", "brie"),
      size = 200,
      replace = TRUE
    )),
    gender = sample(c(0, 1), size = 200, replace = TRUE),
    weight = rtruncnorm(
      n = 200,
      a = 40,
      b = 120,
      mean = 70,
      sd = 25.09
    )
  )


> cheese_df

## # A tibble: 200 x 4
##      age cheese_response gender weight
##    <dbl> <fct>            <dbl>  <dbl>
##  1    45 cheddar              0   62.2
##  2    32 cheddar              0   45.0
##  3    58 cheddar              1   87.6
##  4    28 brie                 0   68.8
##  5    49 gouda                0   88.2
##  6    29 brie                 1   74.5
##  7    49 cheddar              0   74.0
##  8    27 gouda                1   90.3
##  9    28 brie                 0   56.5
## 10    48 mozzarella           0   72.9
## # ... with 190 more rows
```

#### If I just want to run a multinomial regression  and control for age, gender, and weight **without splitting by gender** I could do:

```r
library(nnet)
library(effects)


fit <- nnet::multinom(cheese_response ~ age + gender + weight, data = cheese_df)

average_person_for_control <-
  c(
    age = 50,
    gender = 0.5,
    weight = 75
  )

prediction <-
  effects::Effect("age",
                  fit,
                  given.values = average_person_for_control,
                  xlevels = list(age =
                                   c(45, 90)))


proportions_for_plot <-
  data.frame(prediction$prob, prediction$lower.prob, prediction$upper.prob) %>% 
  slice(1) %>%
  pivot_longer(., cols = everything(), 
               names_to = c(".value", "response"), 
               names_pattern = "(.*)\\.(.*$)") %>%
  rename("lower_ci" = "L.prob",
         "upper_ci" = "U.prob",
         "estimate" = "prob")


ggplot(proportions_for_plot, aes(x = reorder(response, -estimate), y = estimate)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.7, fill = "darkgreen") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci),
                width = 0.2) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(100*round(estimate,2), "%")),
            vjust = 1.6, 
            color = "white", size = 3) +
  xlab("cheese type") +
  ylab("proportion of people choosing this type")
```

[image: controlled_for_no_split]

### However, I'm interested in generating the same bar plot only that it would split bars male vs female

#### This is the kind of plot I'm trying to get

(ignore the values in this demo)
[image]

One approach would be to subset the data by gender, run the same model on each subset, generate two barplots and unite them. However, I want to incorporate `gender` within the model as a factor, and only then output the split bar plot. This is partially taken care of, as `gender` is already part of the model:
`fit <- nnet::multinom(cheese_response ~ age + gender + weight, data = cheese_df)`.

**Still**, as far as splitting the predictions *by* gender, in order to compare them side-by-side in a bar plot, I run into trouble. This is because `effects::Effect()` accepts only a vector into its `given.values` argument. Otherwise, I would have done something like the following to feed the prediction (like I would do if I were to use `predict`):

```r
control_by_gender <-
  expand.grid(
    age = 50,
    weight = 75,
    gender = c(0, 1)
  )

> control_by_gender

##   age weight gender
## 1  50     75      0
## 2  50     75      1
```

Any idea how I could get such a multiple -- rather than focal -- prediction when working on a multinomial model object as seen above? My ultimate goal is the split-by-gender bar plot, like the demo above. I've been using `Effects::effect` for generating the prediction but am open to any substitute that could do the multiple prediction trick.

Comment: This seems to be mainly about code, so should be imgrated to SO.

Comment: Why `slice(1)`?  It seems like you are just getting rid of one age category.

Comment: @andrew_reece, `slice(1)` is because `xlevels` takes 2 values for `age`: `45` and `90`. However, it's a workaround since I'm not interested in `90` at all. But try including only a single value for `xlevels` (e.g. `45`) and see the messy output it gives. So I ended up including 2 values for `xlevels` only to get rid of one later (by `slice`). If you know a more elegant method I'll be grateful. The only reason I use `effects::Effect` is to get a focal prediction given single values for `age`, `weight`, and `gender`. On top of that comes the current post of generating 2 predictions by `gender`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses the same intuition as @Abdessabour Mtk, just with `purrr::map` instead and a bit of refactoring:

```
make_eff_df <- function(gender, fit) {
  Effect("age", fit, xlevels = list(age = c(45, 90)),
         given.values = c(age = 50, weight = 75, gender = gender)) %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    mutate(gender = gender) %>%
    select(gender, matches("[a-z\\.]?prob")) %>%
    slice(1)
}


map_dfr(0:1, make_eff_df, fit) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-gender, names_to = c(".value", "response"), 
               names_pattern = "(.+)\\.(.+$)") %>%
  rename(lower_ci = "L.prob", upper_ci = "U.prob", estimate = "prob") %>%
  mutate(across(1:2, as.factor)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(response, -estimate), y = estimate, fill = gender)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.7, position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci), 
                position = position_dodge(.9),
                width = 0.2) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(estimate, accuracy = 1)),
            vjust = 1.6, color = "white", size = 3, position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  labs(x = "cheese type",
       y = "proportion of people choosing this type")
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

Why not just lapply the levels into the `effects::Effect` call

```r
prediction <- do.call(rbind,lapply(0:1, function(x) {
    eff <- effects::Effect("age",
                  fit,
                  given.values =c(age = 50,
                        weight = 75,
                        gender = x),
                  xlevels = list(age =c(45, 90)))
    data.frame(level=x, eff$prob, eff$lower.prob, eff$upper.prob) %>% slice(1)
    }))


proportions_for_plot <-
  prediction %>% 
  pivot_longer(., cols = !level, 
               names_to = c(".value", "response"), 
               names_pattern = "(.*)\\.(.*$)") %>%
  rename("lower_ci" = "L.prob",
         "upper_ci" = "U.prob",
         "estimate" = "prob")


ggplot(proportions_for_plot, aes(x = as.factor(response), y = estimate, fill=factor(level))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.7,position="dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci), position=position_dodge(.9),
                width = 0.2) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(100*round(estimate,2), "%")),
            vjust = 1.6, 
            color = "white", size = 3, position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  xlab("cheese type") +
  ylab("proportion of people choosing this type")
```

[image]